# Add a summary column with totals

Tags: sql, hive, aggregation

I would like to make a query and add a summary column of a total to a single table (b) from the raw data in table (a) using SQL.

Please refer to the example. Table b is the results of query I want.

Anyone could help on this? Thank you.

[image: example]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to them.

Comment: hi jarlh, i am using HiveSql

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store values calculated from table data. It's too easy to get inconsistent data. (Someone updates table a, but forgets to update table b, for instance.) View, and computed columns are safer.

Comment: Hi jarlh, if i just want to perform query to the results in a single table shown in table b. do u have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Hive at all. The simple way is to have a correlated subquery in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Join`, based on your example, lets call it `test`:

```
Select table1.user, table1.restaurant, table1.spendings, table2.total_spendings
FROM
    (
        SELECT user, restaurant, sum(spending) AS spendings
        FROM test
        GROUP BY user, restaurant
    ) table1
JOIN
    (
        SELECT user, sum(spending) AS total_spendings
        FROM test
        GROUP BY user
    ) table2
ON table1.user = table2.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view (virtual table) instead -
Code for creating a view

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_NAME
AS SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Comment: A view can be a good idea, but your view will not return the expected result. And it needs a column name for the count.

Answer (score 0):

You want window functions:

```
select user, restaurant, sum(spending) as spending,
       sum(sum(spending)) over () as total_spending
from t
group by user, restaurant;
```

You can use `create table as` or `insert` if you want to insert this into a new table.